# Downloading file js

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I have noticed when i download a bigger file it doesent download in smaller packets with a loading bar, you just have to wait a while and then it pops up at 100% is there anyother method that fixes this.

It currently looks like this.

```
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = myUrl;
link.setAttribute("download", data.name);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.remove();
```

I looked for how to use a stream, but im not sure if that is what you use. Thank you.

Comment: That's kind of how browsers work: the download happens _outside_ your page. It's a completely independent network request, entirely unrelated to anything that happens on your page (which is also why if someone closes the tab with your page in it, that download will happily keep going. The download is owned by the browser, not your page)

Answer (score 0):

There are more straightforward ways to download files than using javascript to add a link to the document, clicking the button, and removing it.  The browser doesn't show any progress because it doesn't do that by default.
You have to code a solution that shows and updates the progress as it downloads.  Here is an example of how to initiate a download using javascript with feedback:

```
function downloadURL (url, progress) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
        const reader = res.body.getReader()
        const totalSize = Number(res.headers.get('content-length'))
        let downloadSize = 0
        
        function readData() {
           return reader.read().then( result => {
              if( result.value ) {
                 downloadSize += result.value.length;
                 const percent = Math.floor( (downloadSize / totalSize) * 100 )
                 elem.setAttribute('value', percent)
                 elem.textContent = `${percent} %`
              }

              if( !result.done ) {
                 return readData();
              }
           })
        }
        return readData()
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err))
  })
}

const progressElem = document.body.append('<progress id="file" value="0" max="100"> 0% </progress>')
downloadURL( myUrl, progressElem )
   .then((res) => console.log("Done!", res))
   .finally( () => document.body.remove( progressElem ) );
```

That will download the file, and show a progress bar (unstyled) as it downloads the data.